# Angular: how to access properties of object from external class (in ng-repeat)?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am building a simple angular app to handle orders from customers.
In each order I store the customer's id, and not the whole customer's data (denormalization is o.k., but... :-).
I don't know how to render a list of orders (using `ng-repeat`), displaying the customer's name, too...

My (firebase) data structure is like this:

```
+ myapproot
  + customers
    + -JT5by1W6hylwsbVcfFg
      - name = "Alice"
      - ...
    + ...
  + orders
    + -JUUcRPpWnoyeXzklo9V
      - customerId = "-JT5by1W6hylwsbVcfFg"
      - date = "2014-08-16T16:23:47.047Z"
      - amount = "100"
      - ...
    + ...
```

My view is like this:

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(orderId, order) in orders | orderByPriority">
      <td title="Date of order">
        {{ order.date | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm' }}
      </td>
      <td title="Customer name">
        {{ ??? }}
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My controller is like this:

```
app.controller('OrdersCtrl', function ($scope, Order, Customer) {

  $scope.order = {};
  $scope.orders = Order.all;

  ...
}
```

---

***UPDATE***:
The Answer from 'Sunil D.' is correct, accepted.
This is my *slightly* modified version, since I do not store customer's id inside customer data (I get the id from the parent key), and I want to skip not-object elements:

```
$scope.customersById = {};
$scope.customers = Customer.all;
$scope.customers.$on('loaded', function() {
  angular.forEach($scope.customers, function(customer, id) {
    if (typeof customer === 'object') {
      $scope.customersById[id] = customer;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you could approach this a few ways.  Creating a hash as Sunil has suggested would be a good approach if you only need a few properties, and/or only needed to use them one place.  another option is to create a Directive, like `customer-display` that would take a `customerId` property and output all relevant info about a customer.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a simple example of such directive code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a hash of customers and refer to that in the view:

```
$scope.customersById = {};

angular.forEach($scope.customers, function(customer) {
   $scope.customersById[customer.id] = customer;
});

<td title="Customer name">
    {{customersById[order.customerId].name}}
</td>
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks. I did just found the two little imperfections in the code you suggested, but you have been swifter... :-). One more question: is the data structure I implement a good one, or can you think about something better? I'm quite new to Angularjs, so I can't yet tell if some design choice can lead to future problems (or performance issues, for example...). I mean: with this solution I am forced to load *all* customer data in orders page, right?

Comment: Your data structures seem fine, but in the end it will all depend on how you use them in your application. For example, storing the customer's name name on the order object would solve this too. But that's not very flexible. I briefly looked at the Firebase documentation to see if there was a way to join these two data models when you query for orders (so that they are two separate objects, but the server does the work of associating the customer w/each order). Then you could only make one query for orders. But it still depends on what your app does w/the data ;)

Comment: You could also consider creating an Angular "service" to store the list of customers. This would let you re-use/share the customer data elsewhere in your code. The service could provide the above customers hash as well as the array of customers returned by the server, and finally a "refresh()" function to update data from the server.